# Avoid reordering of keys when merging JSON objects with jq

Tags: json, key, jq

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) I want to unflatten a JSON file.

**Input**

```json
{
  "b": 1,
  "c": 2,
  "a:e": 3,
  "a:d": 4
}
```

**Expected output**

```json
{
  "b": 1,
  "c": 2,
  "a": {
    "e": 3,
    "d": 4
  }
}
```

This code reorders the keys alphabetically.
Why is this and how can I keep the insertion order?

```bash
jq '. as $obj
    | reduce keys[] as $key ({}; . * setpath($key | split(":"); $obj[$key]))'
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "a": {
    "d": 4,
    "e": 3
  },
  "b": 2,
  "c": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keys` sorts the keys, `keys_unsorted` doesn't.

```bash
. as $obj | reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key ({};
  . * setpath($key | split(":"); $obj[$key])
)
```

However, I would rather use `to_entries`:

```bash
reduce to_entries[] as {$key, $value} ({}; 
  setpath($key / ":"; $value)
)
```

```json
{
  "b": 1,
  "c": 2,
  "a": {
    "e": 3,
    "d": 4
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/eoSqANT_j8D)

Comment: I was not aware that `keys` returns a sorted array. Your solution with `to_entries` is more elegant - I will use it ... thank you

Comment: @jpseng Actually, not even `keys_unsorted` guarantees to reflect the insertion order. It rather follows a storage management order which is just "based on" insertion order. From the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#keys,keys_unsorted): "The builtin function `keys` [...] returns its keys in an array. The keys are sorted "alphabetically", by unicode codepoint order [...], regardless of locale settings. [...] The `keys_unsorted` function is just like `keys`, but [...] the keys will not be sorted, instead the keys will roughly be in insertion order."